# preventing reloading of images when appending them with JQuery append()

Tags: jquery, image, browser-cache

I've got an AJAX call that returns some JSON including some image URLs. I want to add images to the DOM for them, but I'm going to be getting the same images over and over again and I don't want to run up my bandwidth costs. The browser's not caching these images for me by default - if I create an img element with JQuery and append it, the browser requests that image each time I do that.

So I added a cache in the form of a hidden div like so:

```
<div id="imageCache" style="display: none;"></div>
```

and then did this in JQuery when looping over JSON objects returned from the server which might have an imageKey on them:

```
if (post.imageKey) {
    var cachedImage = $("#imageCache ." + post.imageKey);

    if (cachedImage.length) {
        var newImage = $(cachedImage).clone();
        $("#" + post.key).append(newImage);
    }
    else {                  
        var newImage = $("<img src='/image?key=" + post.imageKey + "' alt='" + post.title + "' class='offeredPost " + post.imageKey + "'/>");
        $("#" + post.key).append(newImage);

        cachedImage = $(newImage).clone();
        $("#imageCache").append(cachedImage);
    }
}
```

But no joy. The cloned image gets added to the DOM, but then as soon as the JS completes for the page, the browser (Chrome) makes a new request for the image.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The browser probably isn't caching the image because you're using a query string in the SRC. Can you use static URLs for those images instead?

Comment: @mblase75 That's only the case if the querystring changes.  It's like the old trick of adding a random number at the end of a url to force a reload every time.  It only works _because_ the number is different.

Comment: @Archer Thanks, I did remember that -- I just didn't have enough information to be sure that OP's `post.imageKey` wasn't changing every time. Thought I'd throw it out there for him to consider.

Comment: No, that `post.imageKey`'s the same every time - it's the ID for the image. Pulling it out of the query string's no biggy but I think Archer's right.

Answer (score 2):

Use a div with the width and height set to the width and height of the picture and use the background property to load the picture url('myImage.jpg'). Use no-repeat so the picture won't be repeated in case the div is larger than the picture

Comment: +1 and a nice trick is to use also: `background-position: center center;` to keep the 'background' always centered in it's container.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like's it's going to work, but it does require me to know the dims of the image before I load it, which is a bit tricky. Looking at adding something server-side for that and passing it in the AJAX response.

Comment: can't think of any simple solution to that, but you can set the dimensions of the div dynamically each time you're changing the image. use an ajax call to get the dimensions of the image (php GD library has getimagesize() see here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: My server side is Google App Engine so getting the dimensions of an image is not trivial, but it is possible. Details on this bug if anyone else needs it: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5452&can=1&q=image%20height&sort=language%20status&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log